# user.messages.get responding invalid ID

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

when attempting to test out the api explorer for `user.messages: get` I have been getting an `invalid message ID` response.

I am getting the message ID from a recent email in my inbox sent to me, and removed the `<>` from either ends.

response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid id value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid id value"
 }
}
```

I am a bit confused as I am using the powershell module `gshell` and noticed that the same messageID worked in my commands but returned `invalid id value` in the api explorer.

edit:  if I do a inbox search for `rfc822msgid:[messageID]` it returns the correct message

Answer (score 1):

First you have to call the users.messages.list api. It will give a list of messageids. Then we have to call users.message.get api with each messageid to fetch the mail content. You can query the mails with [advanced search options](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) provided by Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `rfc822msgid`, but the Gmail API message id. Try to [**list messages**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and use the `id` you get from that when [**getting**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) the message.

Comment: I dont always have that - I usually end up getting the message ID from the admin inbox search tool

Comment: @Jon If you only have the `Message-ID`, your can first [**list**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with q `rfc822msgid:{Message-ID}` like you said, take the Gmail API message id from that, and then [**get**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) it.